# Method Chaining in EF6 Doesn't Output the correct SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I have the following methods:

```
        private IEnumerable<CTNTransactionsView> RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLS() {
        IQueryable<int> talismanIdCollection = this._cc.TLSTransactionView.Select(x => x.kSECSYSTrans);
        return this._cc.CTNTransactionView
                   .Where(x => !talismanIdCollection.Contains(x.kSECSYSTrans));
    }

    public IEnumerable<CTNTransactionsView> RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLSPast24Hours() {
        DateTime previousDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1.0);
        return this.RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLS()
                   .Where(x => x.dSECSYSTimeStamp >= previousDate);
    }


    public IEnumerable<CTNTransactionsView> RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLSPast24HoursVersionTwo() {
        DateTime previousDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1.0);
        IQueryable<int> talismanIdCollection = this._cc.TLSTransactionView
                                                   .Select(x => x.kSECSYSTrans);
        return this._cc.CTNTransactionView
                   .Where(x => !talismanIdCollection.Contains(x.kSECSYSTrans))
                   .Where(x=> x.dSECSYSTimeStamp >= previousDate);
    }
```

For some reason, the SQL output generated by Entity Framework 6 does not match the results.

The RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLSPast24HoursVersionTwo() method will properly give a SQL Output Statement that has the following:

```
select ...... from ... where ...     AND ([Extent1].[dSECSYSTimeStamp] >= @p__linq__0)}
```

The other one does not have the filter for the dSECSYSTimeStamp when I View the SQL Statement Output.

The methods I am comparing are the RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLSPast24Hours() and the RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLSPast24HoursVersionTwo().

I have compared the SQL using VS as well as attaching a Debug.Writeline() to the Database.Log in the context.

From debugging and looking at the SQL output, one seems to contain the date filter whereas the other doesn't and yet they both provide the correct result.

I have tried looking at the SQL (by breakpointing and seeing the output) from using the following:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Running first method");
        var result = this.repo.RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLSPast24Hours();
        var count = result.Count();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Running Second method");
        var resultTwo = this.repo.RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLSPast24HoursVersionTwo();
        var count2 = resultTwo.Count();
```

I am using EF 6.0.

Note: The results are the same as both do exactly the same thing and output the same result. However, I am curious and would like to understand why the SQL Generated isn't the same?

Comment: the reason is that LINQ will only use LINQ to SQL when it is being used on an IQueryable. `RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLS` returns an IEnumerable. This means that at that point it loads the data into memory, and then does the second `Where` operation on the data in memory...not by altering the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are returning an IEnumerable from your method.  If you do this, you force SQL to run the query (unfiltered) and then use C# to then run the second query.  Alter your internal query to return an IQueryable.  This will allow the unexecuted expression tree to be passed into the second query, which will then be evaluated when your run it.

i.e.

`private IQueryable<CTNTransactionsView> RetrieveCTNTransactionsNotInTLS()`

You should then get the same SQL.

Comment: I should add that this isn't always possible.  A real mistake you can make when building filters like this is that you can't close the SQL connection before you actually evaluated the query.  If your return the IQueryable but don't evaluate it until much later in the code, you might hit this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you just define a query expression, but not use it immediately, in this time, I will add `.ToList()` in the **Linq** expression's end, but you have to change method's return type into a right type like `List<kSECSYSTrans>` before this operation. I just seldom use the type `IEnumerable`.